# Database model to describe IT environment

Tags: sql, database, django, database-design, django-models

I'm looking at writing a Django app to help document fairly small IT environments. I'm getting stuck at how best to model the data as the number of attributes per device can vary, even between devices of the same type. For example, a SAN will have 1 or more arrays, and 1 or more volumes. The arrays will then have an attribute of Name, RAID Level, Size, Number of disks, and the volumes will have attributes of Size and Name. Different SANs will have a different number of arrays and volumes.

Same goes for servers, each server could have a different number of disks/partitions, all of which will have attributes of Size, Used space, etc, and this will vary between servers.

Another device type may be a switch, which won't have arrays or volumes, but will have a number of network ports, some of which may be gigabit, others 10/100, others 10Gigabit, etc.

Further, I would like the ability to add device types in the future without changing the model. A new device type may be a phone system, which will have its own unique attributes which may vary between different phone systems.

I've looked into EAV database designs but it seems to get very complicated very quickly, and I'm unclear on whether it's the best way to go about this. I was thinking something along the lines of the model as shown in the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMnNl.jpg

A bonus would be the ability to create 'snapshots' of environments at a particular time, making it possible to view changes to the environment over time. Adding a date column to the attributes table may be a way to solve this.

For the record, this app won't need to scale very much (at most 1000 devices), so massive scalability isn't a big concern.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, looks like the EAV-esque mdel is a reasonable solution. One other thing I didn't think about, what would be the best way to represent these devices in the code? Would creating an object for each device type, with properties that store dictionaries for each attribute (eg, san_array_1_size, san_array2_size, etc) be a reasonable way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are more comfortable with something along the lines of the image you posted, below is a slightly modified version (sorry I can't upload an image, don't have enough rep).

```
+-------------+
| Device Type |
|-------------|
| type        |--------+
+-------------+        |
                       ^
                  +---------------+     +--------------------+     +-----------+
                  | Device        |----<| DeviceAttributeMap |>----| Attribute |
                  |---------------|     |--------------------|     |-----------|
                  | name          |     | Device             |     | name      |
                  | DeviceType    |     | Attribute          |     +-----------+
                  | parent_device |     | value              |
                  | Site          |     +--------------------+
                  +---------------+       
                       v
+-------------+        |
| Site        |        |
|-------------|        |
| location    |--------+
+-------------+
```

I added a linker table `DeviceAttributeMap` so you can have more control over an `Attribute` catalog, allowing queries for devices with the same `Attribute` but differing values. I also added a field in the Device model named `parent_device` intended as a self-referential foreign key to capture a relationship between a device's parent device. You'll likely want to make this field optional. To make the foreign key `parent_device` optional in Django set the field's null and blank attributes to True.

Answer (score 1):

Since your attributes are per model instance and are different for each instance,
I would suggest going with completely free schema

```
class ITEntity(Model):
    name = CharField()

class ITAttribute(Modle)
    name = CharField()
    value = CharField()
    entity = ForeignKey(ITEntity, related_name="attrs")
```

This is very simple model and you can do the rest, like templates (i.e. switch template, router template, etc) in you app code - its much more straight-forward then using complicated model like EAV (I do like EAV, but this does not seem the usage case for this).

Adding history is also simple - just add timestamp to `ITAttribute`. When changing attribute - create new one instead. Then fetching attribute pick the one with the latest timestamp. That way you can always have point-in-time view of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a document based NoSQL database, like MongoDB. Each document can represent a device with as many different fields as you like.

Comment: I looked into this and while there appears to be third party support for MongoDB with Django, I think it's a bit outside my skill level as I'm fairly new to programming. Definitely something I'll look at in the future though.